# How can we trigger date selection in a WPF calendar control on PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp event

Tags: wpf

How can we trigger date selection in a wpf calendar control on PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp event?

WPF Calendar control date selection will be done on the 'mouse left button down' event. But here I want to do the date selection on mouse left button up event.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution,

Just extend the calendar and override the 'OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown' and OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp as given below,

```
public class CustomCalendar : Calendar
    {
        protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(e.OriginalSource is FrameworkElement element))
            {
                return;
            }

            element.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ButtonBase.ClickEvent));
        }
    }
```